# Wireless exchange between Arduino and Raspberry Pi: choice of protocol

Tags: arduino, protocols, wireless, raspberry-pi, error-correction

Hello oh mighty StackOverflow.com community.

This is the question I've been fiddling with for a while now. I have (will have) an Arduino 2560 talking to RPi using pair of 388 RF transmitter/receiver - so effectively it will be a serial communication. To make matters worse, there will be many transmitters (Arduinos) and a single reciever (RPi). Two questions which I cannot quite figure an answer for:

1. Protocol is extremely primitive - so if I want any error correction, I have to choose it myself. I thought to use something extremely simple like parity bit to start with and see how it goes. Thoughts?
2. Speaking of the protocol itself - how are we going to encode the data? Effectively there will be a single number which I am going to transmit - transmitter ID - accompanied by a boolean flag (sensor active/inactive). What would be the best way to encode the data for serial RF transmission? All to text? I can also transmit this as a stream of bytes, however much that would be, but that would make further porting difficult (Big/Little Endian, word size, etc). Also tried to consider some exotics such as NanoPB no matter how Protocol Buffers are great they are probably overkill for this task. I understand my position is very wobbly here, so I'd appreciate your ideas.
3. Finally, I know it sounds lame but I'm pretty sure someone has done this before and there might even be some sort of cross-platform library which I can use to do my exchange. If this is indeed so, it would be great - I can do what I want to do instead of re-inventing a wheel.

Anyway, here's where I stand. Would appreciate any answers.

This is a [transmitter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8946) I'm using and this is a [receiver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8950).

Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Arduino Virtual Wire library – http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_VirtualWire.html. That works fine with those transmitters and receivers on Arduino and should not be too hard to port to the Raspberry Pi. There is a forum discussion about it at http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=24215&p=239410.

Comment: Thanks, I was considering VirtualWire but didn't find any ready-to-use ports (to be perfectly honest, I didn't even find the source code)

Answer (score 0):

Receive could theoretically be ported to the Raspberry, but you would need real-time access to the processor to use bit-banging for transmitting. Unfortunately, Linux isn't a real-time OS, as the processor spends various amounts of time handling other processes. This wrecks havoc when you try to create a software clock reference. It works well on Arduino where it is only running one program.

There are some hardware kludges that involve a little extra cost and hardware complexity. One is to send the data to the SPI in Mode 0, and wire the MOSI and SCLK pins to the input of an XOR gate IC. Another hardware method would be to program an Arduino or PIC to act as a gateway between the RF modules and the Raspberry Pi using SPI or I2C to handle the RF.

Note: This kludge requires a FIFO buffered SPI UART. Some of the earlier Raspberry Pi models have software SPI, and do not use a hardware FIFO. Check the specs of your particular version.

Someone interested and skilled could also create a kernel module for the Pi to handle this type of link. More info on that topic can be found here:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=39951